Passing id from activity for rawQuery on id column
I'm passing id from item in activity for a rowQuery in my database. I get error :

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: COL_ID_DATA (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Stats WHERE COL_ID_DATA = ?.

Sending id :
btnExport.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            idPass = id;
            DatabaseManager.exportStatsToCSV(getApplicationContext(), fileName,idPass );
        }

Retrieving id :
static int idPass;

public DatabaseManager(@Nullable Context context) {

My table :
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_STATS + "("
            + COL_ID_DATA + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," // column exists !
            + COL_NAME + " TEXT," 
            + COL_BIRTHDAY + " TEXT,"...`

rawQuery in my DatabaseManager:
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_STATS +" WHERE COL_ID_DATA = 
        ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(idPass)});

What's wrong ? Thanks

The rowQuery is for export a row from my db TABLE_STATS to a csv file.
